# Use PowerShell to interpret registry values

Tags: windows, windows-registry, powershell, cmd.exe

Consider the following key, as an example

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command
```

and its `(Default)` value

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

This value determines what will happen when you double click on a `.txt` file.
`%SystemRoot%` and `%1` are variables that can be interpreted by
`cmd.exe`. An equivalent command in PowerShell would look like

```
$env:SystemRoot\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE $args[0]
```

However if you set the  registry value to the Powershell equivalent it will only create an error, because it is `cmd.exe` trying to interpret it, and not PowerShell. Can Windows be set in such a way to allow PowerShell to be the interpreter instead of `cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot set Windows to use PowerShell style variables in the registry. Doing so would be a breaking change for many applications since `cmd.exe` is not the only one that can expand environment variables.

For example, you can expand environment variables using .NET with:

```
[Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables('%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1')
```

You can also enter `%HOME%` in the run dialong (<kbd>Win+R</kbd>) or in the Windows Explorer address bar to open your home directory. Neither of these use `cmd.exe` to expand the variables.

3rd party applications can also parse the strings themselves, and look up the values in the registry. Because of Microsoft's concern for backwards compatibility, I doubt Windows would change the way environment variables are stored in the registry.